# How to get elements from an arraylist using custom sequence

Tags: java

I  have an array list which contains some records ,now i have to extract the records from the list using a sequence i.e i need to retrieve 2 elements at a time and put them into a query.But i am not  getting the result properly.i have posted what i have tried.

```
public class ListFileUtil {

 public static void main (String[] args){
     int count=0;

     List<String> aList=new ArrayList<String>();
     aList.add("Jeet");
     aList.add("Jeet1");
     aList.add("Jeet2");
     aList.add("Jeet3");
     aList.add("Jeet4");
     aList.add("Jeet5");

    Iterator itr=aList.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        count++;
        if(count>=2){
        System.out.println("good code!!!"+itr.next());
        }

    }
}
```

}

i am trying to extract two element at a time and then the next 2 and so on.But my logic is not correct .somebody please help.

Comment: `while(itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("good code!!!"+itr.next()+" "+itr.next());
}`

Comment: For above condition, it will throw NoSuchElementException ( when size is even)

Answer (score 0):

Below will print for every alternated list.

```
 while(itr.hasNext()){
    count++;
    String val = (String)itr.next();
    if(count%2 == 0){
    System.out.println("good code!!!"+val);
    }

 }
```

Output

```
good code!!!Jeet1
good code!!!Jeet3
good code!!!Jeet5
```

Answer (score 0):

simple try like this :

```
    int i=0;
    while(i<aList.size())
    {
        if(i==(aList.size()-1))
        System.out.println(aList.get(i));
        else {
            System.out.println(aList.get(i));
            System.out.println(aList.get(i + 1));
            System.out.println("*******");
        }
        i=i+2;
    }
```